# Update programmatically value of field collection item

Tags: stream-wrappers

I want to update a field collection

I have the following:

```
function pdf_app_node_presave($node) {
    if (!$node->is_new) {
        global $base_url;
        if($node->type == 'article') {
            $node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);


            foreach ($node_wrapper->field_chapitres->value() as $library) {
                $library_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $library);

                  $books = $library_wrapper->field_subchapters->value();
                  foreach($books as $book){
                    $book_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $book);
                    $title ='sfsdfsd';
                    $book_wrapper->field_pdf_title2->set($title); 
                    $book_wrapper->save();

                  }
            }


            field_attach_update('node', $node);





        }

    }

}
```

But i get an error i think i should use something like

```
    $values[0]['field_title'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = $title;
```

but it is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Update value of field collection item use `Set` Something like:

```
$book_wrapper->field_title->set($title);
```

For more info See [Entity metadata wrappers Docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers) ***Example using field collections*** Section.

Comment: It is not working the field is not updated I put now the qll code in a new edit

Comment: Did you check what gives `$library` variable inside the Foreach?

Comment: When i do dpm($library);inside the foreach i get FieldCollectionItemEntity

Comment: try to add `$book_wrapper->setHostEntity('node', $node);` before `$book_wrapper->save();`

Comment: I am getting bool(false) 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method EntityDrupalWrapper::setHostEntity() when i add $book_wrapper->setHostEntity('node', $node);

Comment: Sorry `setHostEntity` Should be on `FieldCollectionItemEntity` not  on `EntityDrupalWrapper` So try with  `$book->setHostEntity('node', $node);`

Comment: i am getting Exception: The host entity may be set only during creation of a field collection item.